# Detect edge://flags/#edge-click-once enabled in Chromium Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, clickonce, chromium

We have an application that starts via Click Once in the browser. Since Chromium Edge, Click Once isn't enabled by default. You can enable this setting via edge://flags/#edge-click-once.

I would like to detect if this setting is enabled. If not i would like to direct them to a support page with instructions to enable it.

I don't have access to clients browser in anyway. So I would like to detect this via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flags can't be accessed through js, because js codes can be executed in any browsers. We can't only target the features in a certain browser. I also searched a lot and find no way. Maybe Extension can do this, but I think that will take a lot of effort to research.

As this feature is not enabled by Edge Chromium by default, I think the easiest workaround is to detect the browser version, if Edge Chromium, then remind the user to check if the feature is enabled:

```js
var checkbrowser = (function(agent) {

  if (agent.indexOf("edg") > -1) {  //check if Edge Chromium
    return "the page of showing how to enable clickonce support";
  } else {
    return "not Edge Chromium"
  }

})(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

document.body.innerHTML = checkbrowser;
```

Besides, if your application is used in an enterprise and someone has access to the group policy, you can also suggest IT department to set this [group policy: ClickOnceEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#clickonceenabled) to enable clickonce in Edge Chromium.

Comment: The group policy lead is spot on, but the redirect misses the point of the question because it fires every time.  The need is for this to happen only once.